# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Symbol' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Map<dynamic, dynamic> Tried calling: []("symbol))

Tags: flutter, dart

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Type' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Map<dynamic, dynamic> Tried calling: ):

am trying to call the user from Map to the user profile UI if there is a solution
NOTE: sorry for the chaos is made just to fill the post that was mostly code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Signal {
  final String sg_symbol;
  final String sg_timeframe;
  final String sg_exchange;
  final String sg_unitDatetime;
  final int sg_signal;
  final String sg_algorithm;

  Signal({
    required this.sg_symbol,
    required this.sg_timeframe,
    required this.sg_exchange,
    required this.sg_unitDatetime,
    required this.sg_signal,
    required this.sg_algorithm,
  });

  factory Signal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Signal(
      sg_symbol: json['symbol'],
      sg_timeframe: json['timeframe'],
      sg_exchange: json['exchange'],
      sg_unitDatetime: json['unit_datetime'],
      sg_signal: json['signal'],
      sg_algorithm: json['algorithm'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Signal>> fetchSignal() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://neutiad2.gabia.io/signal'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // 만약 서버로의 요청이 성공하면, JSON을 파싱합니다.
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    List<dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
    List<Signal> allSignal =
        body.map((dynamic item) => Signal.fromJson(item)).toList();
    return allSignal;
  } else {
    // 만약 요청이 실패하면, 에러를 던집니다.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Signal');
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  Future<List<Signal>>? signal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    signal = fetchSignal();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('info', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder<List<Signal>>(
                  //통신데이터 가져오기
                  future: signal,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return buildList(snapshot.data);
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}에러!!");
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget buildList(snapshot) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 150,
      child: ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red.shade100),
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
                height: 150,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('고객번호:' + snapshot[i].symbol.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('고객명:' + snapshot[i].timeframe.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('계좌 아이디:' + snapshot[i].exchange.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('잔액:' + snapshot[i].unitDatetime.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('잔액:' + snapshot[i].signal.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('잔액:' + snapshot[i].algorithm.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
    PointerDeviceKind.touch,
    PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
    // etc.
  };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The response will be a Map, not a List

`List<dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);`

Change it to

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
```

Comment: @이상현 you can mark as answer while it solves your issue